# Python package versus projects naming conventions

Tags: python, pep8, pep

PEP 8 suggests to use single name words for packages with underscores being discouraged. 
[PEP 8 - Package/Module Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)

PEP 423 suggests to use a single period to split the project's company name and what it does.  But it also says you should use the same name for packages and project names which would go against the style guide in PEP 8. I haven't seen any examples actually using the 423 convention, although I'm sure it exists.

[PEP 423 - Project Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#private-including-closed-source-projects-use-a-namespace)

[PEP 423 - Single Name per Project/Package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#use-a-single-name)

So what is the suggested approach to use and an example project?

Comment: A concrete example would be very helpful here...

Comment: So as the links so PEP 423 suggests something like:

Package name: "kheops.pyramid", i.e. import kheops.pyramid
Project name: "kheops.pyramid", i.e. pip install kheops.pyramid

but PEP 8 would suggest something like "pyramid"

Comment: Since PEP 432's current status is "Deferred"—even though it's over 6 years old—I'd ignore it.

Comment: this seems pretty clear: "Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged."